# Force NuGet pack to use short folder names for PCL projects

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, portable-class-library

I'm having a problem with NuGet producing different output folders when run locally to the version on my build server.

When I build my PCL project locally (using nuget 2.8.6), the folder structure within the nuget package is:

```
lib
- portable-net45 win wpa81 wp80 MonoAndroid10 xamarinios10 MonoTouch10
  - HC.Common.dll
```

However when I build it on our build server (TeamCity, nuget 2.8.2) I get the following folders:

```
lib
- portable-Profile259
  - HC.Common.dll
```

How can I ensure that both builds output consistent folder structures? It makes switching between the "published" version and my test versions quite tricky as the reference paths do not match between versions.

Is there a way to force nuget to use the short "Profile259" name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet will normally replace the PCL profile with the individual target frameworks if it can determine them.

On your build server it looks like you do not have the the PCL profile xml files installed so NuGet is not converting the directory. So I am assuming you are using `NuGet pack YourProject.csproj`. If you used `NuGet pack YourNuGet.nuspec` the directories in the .nupkg would be the same on both machines.

I do not know of any NuGet package that uses a PCL directory of the form portable-Profile78 and I am surprised this works but it seems to. All NuGet packages with PCLs have directories of the form:

```
portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10
```

So to make them consistent on both machines you will need to either install the PCL profiles on the build server or use `NuGet pack YourNuSpec.nuspec` so that the directories are not renamed by NuGet.exe.

Comment: Thanks for that Matt, do you know where I'd get the PCL profile XML files from? Is it best to grab them from my local machine or is there a standard location?

Comment: No worries, found [something here](http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/11/16/InstallingPortableClassLibrariesForXamarinStudio/)

Comment: It will be the simplest to just copy them from your local machine. Otherwise you are left with either installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or above, or going through a very manual process of installing the Portable Library tools, and installing the v4.6 libraries, which is described in this [blog post](http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/11/16/InstallingPortableClassLibrariesForXamarinStudio/)